# Turn Not On X, But On Y

Tags: word-order, phrasal-verbs, ellipsis

I have some question about continuation fragments, or ellipsis fragments:

> [source](http://www.economist.com/news/leaders/21616957-ditching-union-would-be-mistake-scotland-and-tragedy-country-it-leaves)
>   In the end the referendum will ***turn not on*** calculations of taxes and oil revenue, ***but on*** identity and power.

Because "*turn on*" is a single unbreakable verb phrase, the example appears to break it up by using "*turn not on  X,  but on Y*" pattern.  Would my following rewrite be better?

> In the end the referendum will ***turn on not*** calculations of taxes and oil revenue, ***but*** identity and power.

,where I used the "*turn on NOT X, but Y*" (different from "*turn NOT on X, but ON Y*") pattern.

Comment: It is not a single verb phrase.  It is the combination of a verb and the head of a following preposition phrase which, taken together, have slightly noncompositional meaning.

Comment: But your question is still interesting, despite the mistaken assumption.

Comment: @snailboat So, the example is wrong?

Comment: @meatie No, the example you gave of “turn not on X but on Y” is ***not wrong*** at all, merely somewhat trickier to parse. *Turn not on X but on Y* is the same as *Turn on not X but Y*. Consider “That will depend not on taxes but on identity” and notice how the normally “unbreakable“ *depend on* gets interrupted by the first half of a *not . . . but* construct. That is all that is happening here. So *not . . . but* is a shorter version of *not only . . . but also*, and the negation can intercede in things you would not normally think could be subject to injections like this.

Comment: A version that would be easier to read (for native speakers as well) would be, "the referendum will not turn on calculations ... but on identity and power".

Answer (score 1):

In the first quote you are essentially saying:

> In the end the referendum **will turn not on** calculations of taxes and oil revenue, **but (will turn) on** identity and power.

The second "will turn" is implied, and can be skipped without changing the meaning.

Comment: So, the example is wrong?

Comment: If you are referring to your rewrite, I don't think you could say "not calculations" (there really isn't such a thing). I did not change the first example, just added explanatory words that can be omitted. So as written it is OK.